# AzureFunction BlobTrigger: Azure.RequestFailedException at Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueRestClient

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My blobTrigger is working on my local machine but when I try to publish or deploy on Azure I get an error.

On my storageaccount I have selected "Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account".
I have the system managed identity for the functionApp and I have the following RBAC roles:
Storage Blob Data Contributor
Storage Blob Data Owner
Storage Queue Data Contributor

I have a Vnet Integration and a Blob private endpoint is present in the storage account.

Should I create a Queue private endpoint?
Any tips in general how to resolve this issue?

From traces:

```
Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.Listeners.CompositeListener' for function 'BlobTriggerExample'
```

From Exceptions:

```
Azure.RequestFailedException at Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueRestClient+<GetPropertiesAsync>d__14.MoveNext

This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:b2d8d0a2-1003-0052-01a3-553df1000000
Time:2023-03-13T11:59:00.8056457Z
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:b2d8d0a2-1003-0052-01a3-553df1000000
Time:2023-03-13T11:59:00.8056457Z</Message></Error>

Headers:
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: b2d8d0a2-1003-0052-01a3-553df1000000
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationFailure
Date: Mon, 13 Mar 2023 11:58:59 GMT
Content-Length: 246
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Created the .NET 6 Function App in the VNet and allowed a blob private endpoint on the Storage Account Networking Menu.

**Blob Trigger with Queue binding**:

```cs
 public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("devhack/{name}", Connection = "ConnStr")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log,
            [Queue("devqueue", Connection = "ConnStr")] IAsyncCollector<string> queueCollector)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            await queueCollector.AddAsync(name);
        }
```

[image]

Also, in the Function App Configuration > Added the 3 Application Settings related to VNet like `WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET`, `WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER` and `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` present in this similar GitHub Issue [1349](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1349) made it work.

[image]